# skpsmtp can not implement on my project

Tags: objective-c, skpsmtpmessage

So, I want to send email inside my app, but when I import skpsmtp, there are just tones of errors, I added -ObjC flag, imported CFNetwork.framework, but I just got a lot of errors from ARC, is there any decent way to solve this problem?

Comment: take a screenshot and show the errors, maybe I can help....

Comment: It's so nice of you, can I have your email address? cuz I can not post images since I'm new here without enough reputation...

Comment: ah... add my skype: haphanquang